# Movie not playing in Galaxy S GT-I9003?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a phone Galaxy S (GT-I9003) that is unable to play a video with resolution (320x480) while all the other models of Galaxy S are able to display that video.

Here are the logs

```
10-09 06:44:54.232: W/MediaPlayer(1907): info/warning (1, 26)
10-09 06:44:54.232: E/PlayerDriver(1278): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
10-09 06:44:54.232: E/MediaPlayer(1907): error (1, -1)
10-09 06:44:54.232: W/System.err(1907): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at com.MovieController.startMovie(MovieController.java:180)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at com.MovieController.show(MovieController.java:88)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at com.MovieController.play(MovieController.java:120)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at com.android.sphybrid.D2CommandController.execute(D2CommandController.java:73)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at com.android.sphybrid.WGFWebViewClient.doWithTitle(WGFWebViewClient.java:114)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at com.android.sphybrid.WGFWebViewClient.onPageFinished(WGFWebViewClient.java:93)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at jp.android.survivors.WebViewClient.onPageFinished(WebViewClient.java:96)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:281)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4632)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-09 06:44:54.240: W/System.err(1907):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 06:44:54.240: I/MovieFile(1907): Movie File: <null>
10-09 06:44:54.248: W/PlayerDriver(1278): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete
10-09 06:44:54.279: I/AudioFlinger(1278): getNextBuffer() no more data for track 4096 on thread 0x34cc8
10-09 06:44:55.709: D/wpa_supplicant(1474): wpa_driver_tista_driver_cmd LINKSPEED
10-09 06:44:55.709: D/wpa_supplicant(1474): Link Speed command
10-09 06:44:55.709: D/wpa_supplicant(1474): buf LinkSpeed 54
10-09 06:44:56.287: I/AudioStreamOutALSA(1278): (virtual android::status_t android::AudioStreamOutALSA::standby())  enter
10-09 06:44:56.373: D/AudioStreamOutALSA(1278): Output standby called!!. Turn off PCM device.
10-09 06:44:56.373: I/ALSAStreamOps(1278): [ALSAStreamOps]codecOff mode = 0
10-09 06:44:56.373: D/ALSAControl(1278):  ALSAControl::set index = 0 
10-09 06:44:56.373: I/ALSAControl(1278): <set>id = 1079651552, info = 1079651272, name = Amp Enable
10-09 06:44:56.373: I/ALSAControl(1278): <set>mHandle Success 215600
10-09 06:44:56.420: D/BT HS/HF(1489): gsmAsuToSignal=27
10-09 06:44:56.420: D/ALSAControl(1278):  ALSAControl::set index = 0 
10-09 06:44:56.420: I/ALSAControl(1278): <set>id = 1079651552, info = 1079651272, name = Idle Mode
10-09 06:44:56.420: I/ALSAControl(1278): <set>mHandle Success 215600
10-09 06:44:56.490: I/AudioStreamOutALSA(1278): [AudioOutLock]Relase_wake_Lock
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the movie i was trying to play in Android 2.2.1 was in some other codec (JVT/AC) and resolution was (320 x 480). I changed the codec to MPEG-4 without changing the resolution, it started working. I suppose it is an unsupported format.